# How to chop/mince meat?

Tags: equipment, meat

How can I chop or mince meat more easily?

Currently I just use a knife and chop it up.

Meat grinders are no good. I am not trying to make sausage. I want to chop the meat up, not turn it into goo. Most meat grinders don't even have a hole big enough for a chicken breast or steak.

Is there any kind of device that you can just put a cooked chicken breast in it and it chops it up into small pieces? Just to make it clear what I am trying to do:

**------INPUT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------OUTPUT--------**

[image][image]

Comment: That output does not look like "minced" meat... it looks like "roughly chopped" or possibly "cubed". In the UK, for example, "minced" actually means "ground". If you google "minced meat" and look at the images, all of the images are of ground meat.

Comment: @Catija I considered using the word "chopped" rather than minced.

Comment: If that image is what you want, you do not want "minced" meat... you should change your terminology.

Comment: @Catija: just because Brits don't know what "minced" means doesn't mean we have to imitate them. :) ("Grated" is another word in that category: Brits will happily talk about grated mozzarella, even though grating mozzarella is not physically possible, because they're actually using "grated" to mean "shredded".) But you're correct in the sense that the Output picture is what I would call "chopped"; "minced" would be quite a bit smaller than that.

Comment: @Marti Every example image of "minced" I can find is what Americans call "ground"... Even in the US, we'd refer to it as a "rough ground"... not anything like what the image looks like.

Comment: Okay, maybe we need to get Klondike Kat to give his opinion.

Comment: @Catija I think that's more because we don't really use "minced" for meat in the US, so the UK English meaning dominates. But if you look at, say, minced garlic, it's clear that it means very finely chopped, not crushed/ground. Either way, the meat in the picture is just chopped; it's not *that* fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a vegetable dicer. [This professional one](http://www.vegetablescutter.com/product/nemco-57500-2-38-easy-chopper-iii-vegetable-dicer/) specifically says it works for chicken breast. If you have a lot of chicken to dice it maybe worth it, but it won't be real quick to clean.

[image: Professional Vegetable Dicer]

If this is too much machine for what you want to accomplish, smaller home versions are made, something like this [home vegetable dicer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PSY2CJA) might work for you.

[image: Home Vegetable Dicer]

Answer (score 2):

A food processor on pulse setting should be able to do thing.

Comment: Most instructions I have seen require cutting the meat into cubes before putting it in the food processor. This is exactly what I do not want to spend time doing.

Comment: A very rough chop is all that's required before the food processor. With cooked chicken breasts you could probably tear them.

Comment: @ChrisH But if you look at the "output" image, a "rough chop" is what the OP wants. They don't actually want minced meat.

Comment: @Catija I think Chris H means a very large rough chop, which the food processor would then turn into an irregular but fairly fine chop.

Comment: @Catija, Jefromi is right. I was thinking of cutting each of the input pieces into 3-4 chunks so they'd go in the food processor more easily. It's hard to tell without scale (especially on a small screen) but the output looks quite find.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put your cooked chicken breast into freezer for half an hour. You don't want/need it to turn into stone, half-frozen should be enough. After that just use a regular blender on pulse. Make sure not to overdo it. It would take literally 2-3 short (1-2s) pulses to chop it the way you want.

Also, I would cut the breast into 2-3 pieces before freezing to allow for easier and more consistent chopping in the blender.